# How to do mysql LEFT JOIN for Google multiple line chart (php, mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, linechart

I am trying to do a LEFT JOIN (in mysql/php) with two tables to create JSON Table for use with Google line chart. But for some reason, the sql is not populating data in the json table although when I test the same sql directly in phpadmin I am getting the right output.

I have 2 tables - Anxiety and Fatigue - and the join is made on userid and date. Both tables have a "Rating" column that I am trying to chart and so I am trying to get date, anxiety.rating, fatigue.rating into the json table ..

Here is the basic php code that I am using:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT anxiety.date, anxiety.rating, fatigue.rating FROM anxiety LEFT JOIN fatigue ON (anxiety.userid = fatigue.userid) AND (anxiety.date = fatigue.date");
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(

array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Anxiety rating', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'Fatigue rating', 'type' => 'number')
);

/* Extract the information from $result */
foreach($result as $row) {

  $sub_array = array();
  $sub_array[] =  array("v" => $row["anxiety.date"]);
  $sub_array[] =  array("v" => (int) $row["anxiety.rating"]);
  $sub_array[] =  array("v" => (int) $row["fatigue.rating"]);
  $rows[] =  array("c" => $sub_array);          
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsontable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsontable;
```

This is what I am getting if I run the sql query from within phpadmin:

```
2019-07-14  4 1
2019-07-09  5 NULL
2019-07-03  2 NULL
2019-07-01  3 4
```

And this is what I am getting as JSONTable output (which as you can see is not correct):

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"string"},{"label":"Anxiety 
rating","type":"number"},{"label":"Fatigue rating","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":
[{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":null},
{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":0}]}]}
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong with the way the data is getting loaded into the json table since the sql query seems to be working ... Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated ...

Comment: the PHP code has a formatting error as the syntax highlighting is al wrong, pretty sure it missing a `"` on the first line

Comment: what is the formatting error? thanks.

Comment: never mind i fixed it, check if your running code is correct if you copy/paste it..

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but the issue still persists ...

Comment: This is what I tested ...$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT anxiety.date, anxiety.rating, fatigue.rating FROM anxiety LEFT JOIN fatigue ON (anxiety.userid = fatigue.userid) AND (anxiety.date = fatigue.date)");

Comment: *" I fixed that but the issue still persists "* Where did i say that would change the JSON structure.. Annyhow you should edit the question how a correct Google multiple line chart JSON structure should look like, we are not here to fill in the blanks in the question if you know what i mean..

Comment: How does `$result` compare to `phpadmin`output?

Comment: I add "echo $result;" and it just shows "Array" ...

Comment: "which as you can see is not correct" - No, I don't see. What would be the correct result?

Comment: The output from the phpadmin shown above that ..

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the problem .. However, I have columns with the same name (rating) in the two different tables. How do I specify that when I build the jsontable? If I keep $row["rating"] it seems to be taking the value from the first table. ...

Comment: I saw that too, after I posted my comment. See my answer. You should use column aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a query like

```
SELECT 
  anxiety.date,
  anxiety.rating,
  fatigue.rating
...
```

and you fetch the data with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` - The values are stored in an associative array indexed by column names without the table prefix. So you have to access them with `$row["date"]` instead of `$row["anxiety.date"]`. But `anxiety.rating` and `fatigue.rating` are returned with the same column name, and PHP/PDO will write them under the same index (`$row["rating"]`). That means, the value of `anxiety.rating` will be overwritten by the value of `fatigue.rating`. To avoid that, you should use column aliases in your query. So change your query to

```
SELECT 
  anxiety.date,
  anxiety.rating as anxiety_rating,
  fatigue.rating as fatigue_rating
...
```

and access the data with `$row["date"]`, `$row["anxiety_rating"]` and `$row["fatigue_rating"]`.

Comment: I am new to this group. I am not sure how I should notify that Paul Spiegel's solution answered my query ...